# how to get data in spinner from database in Kivy

Tags: python, python-2.7, kivy, kivy-language

## test.py

```
import sqlite3 as lite

from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.uix.treeview import TreeView, TreeViewLabel, TreeViewNode
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty


Window.size = (700, 530)

con = lite.connect('demo.db')
con.text_factory = str
cur = con.cursor()


def populate_tree_view(tree_view, parent, node):
    if parent is None:
        tree_node = tree_view.add_node(TreeViewLabel(text=node['node_id'],
                                                     is_open=True))
    else:
        tree_node = tree_view.add_node(TreeViewLabel(text=node['node_id'],
                                                     is_open=True), parent)

    for child_node in node['children']:
        populate_tree_view(tree_view, tree_node, child_node)


tree = [{'node_id': 'Test2',
         'children': []},
        {'node_id': 'Test3',
         'children': []}]


class TreeViewLabel(Label, TreeViewNode):
    pass


class TreeviewGroup(Popup):
    treeview = ObjectProperty(None)
    tv = ObjectProperty(None)

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(TreeviewGroup, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.tv = TreeView(root_options=dict(text="Test1"),
                           hide_root=False,
                           indent_level=4)
        for branch in tree:
            populate_tree_view(self.tv, None, branch)
        self.remove_widgets()
        self.treeview.add_widget(self.tv)

    def remove_widgets(self):
        for child in [child for child in self.treeview.children]:
            self.treeview.remove_widget(child)


class GroupScreen(Screen):
    groupName = ObjectProperty(None)
    popup = ObjectProperty(None)

    def display_groups(self, instance):
        if len(instance.text) > 0:
            self.popup = TreeviewGroup()
            self.popup.open()


class Group(App):
    #cur.execute("SELECT * FROM `m_state` order by state_id asc")
    #rows = cur.fetchall()
    #print(rows)
    rows = [(1, 'test1', 111), (2, 'test2', 112), (3, 'test3', 113), (4, 'test4', 114)]
    def build(self):
        self.root = Builder.load_file('test.kv')
        return self.root


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Group().run()
```

## test.kv

## :kivy 1.10.0

```
<TreeViewLabel>:
    on_touch_down:
        app.root.stateName.text = self.text
        app.root.popup.dismiss()

<TreeviewGroup>:
    id: treeview
    treeview: treeview
    title: "Select City"
    size_hint: None, None
    size: 400, 400
    auto_dismiss: False

    BoxLayout
        orientation: "vertical"
        BoxLayout:
            id: treeview
        Button:
            size_hint: 1, 0.1
            text: "Close"
            on_release: root.dismiss()


<CustomLabel@Label>:
    text_size: self.size
    valign: "middle"
    padding_x: 5

<SingleLineTextInput@TextInput>:
    multiline: False

<GreenButton@Button>:
    background_color: 1, 1, 1, 1
    size_hint_y: None
    height: self.parent.height * 0.150

GroupScreen:
    stateName: stateName

    GridLayout:
        cols: 2
        padding : 30,30
        spacing: 10, 10
        row_default_height: '40dp'

        CustomLabel:
            text: 'State Name'

        SingleLineTextInput:
            id: stateName
            on_text: root.display_groups(self)

        CustomLabel:
            text: 'State Code'

        Spinner:
            text: "State Code"
            values: ["111", "112", "113", "114"]
            #background_color: color_button if self.state == 'normal' else color_button_pressed
            background_down: 'atlas://data/images/defaulttheme/spinner'
            #color: color_font
            #option_cls: Factory.get("MySpinnerOption")
            #size_hint: None, None


        CustomLabel:
            text: 'City Name'

        SingleLineTextInput:
            id: cityName

        CustomLabel:
            text: 'Short Name'

        SingleLineTextInput:
            id: shortName

        CustomLabel:
            text: 'Pin Code'

        SingleLineTextInput:
            id: pinCode

        GreenButton:
            text: 'Ok'

        GreenButton:
            text: 'Cancel'

        Label:

        Label:
```

Can someone help me?
 1. In above image state code shows 111,112,113,114 which are static.How to show dynamic these state code.I am retrieve data from database which looks
 rows = [(1, 'test1', 111), (2, 'test2', 112), (3, 'test3', 113), (4, 'test4', 114)]

In third index value are coming 111,112,113,114.How to put these value in spinner.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can set a listproperty attribute in your group class then in the kv set the values of the spinner with this list:

in the **.py**:

```
...

class Group(App):
    #cur.execute("SELECT * FROM `m_state` order by state_id asc")
    #rows = cur.fetchall()
    #print(rows)
    rows = [(1, 'test1', 111), (2, 'test2', 112), (3, 'test3', 113), (4, 'test4', 114)]
    r = ListProperty()
    r = [str(t[2]) for t in rows]

...
```

then in the **.kv**:

```
...

Spinner:
    text: "State Code"
    values: app.r

...
```

I have used Lisproperty in case the values change in the future

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: @yashkumar I was answering to your question 'add search filter' but it seems that you have deleted it

Comment: i am really sorry.I I uploaded it back.Thank you